# Navigation text fading in-out using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a portfolio for me. I wish to have a fading in-out effect while I roll over the navigational links (which is pure text). Is there any way to get the fading effect using css ? Or what should I do for that ? Please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ways to do this.

**CSS3:**

Using `-webkit-transition`.

```
#fademe {
   opacity: 0.5;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
}

#fademe:hover {
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

**jQuery (Javascript):**

jQuery's [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) and [`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo) methods.

```
$("#fademe").hover(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(1);
}, function(){
   $(this).fadeTo(0.5);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check out [CSS transitions - MDC Doc Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_transitions)

or [Different Transitions for Hover On / Hover Off | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/different-transitions-for-hover-on-hover-off/)

from css-tricks:

```
#thing {
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;

  /* HOVER OFF */
   -webkit-transition: padding 2s;
}

#thing:hover {
   padding: 20px;
   border-radius: 15px;

  /* HOVER ON */
   -webkit-transition: border-radius 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery [fadein](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeout](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut) to do it.